# How to find people who clicked on a specific campaign using Mailchimp API v3

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

How do I find the list of all people who clicked on a specific campaign through `Mailchimp API v3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Email Activity](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/) is what you are looking for. the emails field contains all emails that opened the campain.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, I also wanted to ask you that, I cannot extract email-activity of more than 5000 people for a particular campaign using Mailchimp API v3 through R or cURL. Is there a limit for the same or is there a better way to extract data of more than 5000 people for a campaign through API ? Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is pagination. You can either iterate over more records using offset in the query parameter, or increase the count query parameter.Note that if you set count to high, the request might take to long and time out. A trick here could be to use a batch call with a single large GET method (with count 1000000 etc.). If you happen to use node, I wrote a npm module that will make batch handling a little easier: [mailchimp-api-v3](https://github.com/thorning/node-mailchimp) (if not you can take a look for inspiration) The batch trick is described at the bottom

Comment: Thorning is right -- one thing to add: batch requests don't need a count parameter. If it is omitted, the batch request will return all results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did as both of you said, but using Batch Operations I am trying to retrieve email-activity of 200000 people, it nearly took me 4 hours. Is there a faster way to do it ?

Comment: did you make it a batch call with only one operation, or a batch call with 200000 operations? If you made a batch call with only 1 operation, I think it is likely the fastest you can get it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Batch call was made with 1 operation only.

Comment: this is my batch operation  ("campaign_id" is the id of the particular campaign with 200000 people in it, so can it be faster than this ?)- {"operations": [ { "method": "GET", "path": "/reports/"campaign_id"/email-activity", "operation_id" : "3" } ] }

Comment: How to GET 3 fields from email-activity of 200,000 people through BATCH operations ? Thank you.

Comment: I mean that I want to GET email_address, campaign_id and email_id(which are present in email-activity along with many other things) of all the people using BATCH operations. Thank you.

Comment: You can try to use the fields query parameter to limit the returned fields

Comment: I am trying to GET information(specific fields from email-activity), how should I do it in Batch GET requests in Mailchimp api v3? This is my code -

{
"operations": [
  {
    "method": "GET", 
    "path": "/reports/campaign_id/email-activity",
   "operation_id" : "123"
  }
]
}
With the above code, the entire email-activity is extracted, I only need few fields from email-activity like "email_address" and "campaign_id". How do I do it using BATCH GET request using Mailchimp API v3? Thank you

Comment: I am not able to parse locally stored JSON file which looks something like this-

[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":"{\"emails\":[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":[]},{\"campaign_id\":\"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}}}] As you can see this - '\'(backslash)is present everywhere, and I am unable to parse it. Could anyone please help. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Thorning , I saw your link -  https://github.com/thorning/node-mailchimp  But in this link I saw a code, how do I store the returned Batch_id in a variable in this code -    mailchimp.batch({
  method : 'get',
  path : '/lists/id/members',
  query : {
    count  : 10000000000,
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  //result is the same as a normal .get request
})

Comment: [Batch call](https://github.com/thorning/node-mailchimp#batch-calls). You can add an options object as the last argument. ´wait:false´ will return the raw result including the batch id