# Limit to extracting details(like email-activity) using Mailchimp API v3 through R and cURL?

Tags: r, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I cannot extract email-activity of more than 5000 people for a particular campaign using Mailchimp API v3 through R or cURL. Is there a limit for the same or is there a better way to extract data of more than 5000 people for a campaign through API ?

Comment: this seems like a question for mailchimp support, or maybe there's a developer forum site for mailchimp

Answer (score 1):

The comment in response to the answer on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741487/how-to-find-people-who-clicked-on-a-specific-campaign-using-mailchimp-api-v3) solves this one. In short: either make use of pagination as described in MailChimp's [Getting Started Guide](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/), or make use of their [batch end-points](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.